# MariaDB / MySql Warning after Netdata installation. "Access denied for user 'netdata'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" How to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb, netdata

I have configured Netdata on an Ubuntu 20.04 Server LEMP server, according to [this Linuxbabe.com tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/monitoring/linux-server-performance-monitoring-with-netdata).

After installation, I run the following command

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
```

which returns the following warning:

```
[Warning] Access denied for user 'netdata'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

1. What does this mean in regards to Netdata functionality?
2. Does this mean Netdata is misconfigured?
3. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a netdata user in the db as per here?

Netdata needs its own db user with specific privileges.

https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/data-collection/database-servers/mysql-and-mariadb#create-netdata-user

Comment: Thanks @andrewm4894. I installed netdata with the netdata setup script using the command `bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh) --disable-telemetry`. Netdata is working. But when I run `SELECT user FROM mysql.user;` in mariadb, no "netdata" user appears. How is netdata working without a database user? What did the setup script do to make things work without using a netdata db user?

Comment: Also when I run `SHOW DATABASES;' in mysql, I see no database for netdata. So apparently netdata is running without a database and database user. How is this possible?

Comment: @DanRan you need to create a netdata user as per docs link i shared.